# Run as administrator option not ava.when right clicked on the script file of powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I had developed a powershell script file and saved it in the desktop. when i right click on the setup file it is not showing "Run as administrator" option. What to do for that?

Comment: so you have a powershell script only, or you packed it into a setup file, exe or msi?

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way:

- Create a desktop icon for `powershell "C:\path\script.ps1"`
- Right-click the icon and select Properties
- Click Advanced
- Click "Run as administrator"
- Click OK.